# Background vertically aligned with div

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to create a full width background image that aligns vertically with a centered div. Should I create a wrapper around all the content, or is there another way to do this (without absolute positioning)? Thanks.

[alt text http://img229.imageshack.us/img229/7391/99479284.png](http://img229.imageshack.us/img229/7391/99479284.png)

EDIT: Sorry if I didn't explain this very well. I've changed the image.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you post a link? How is the div centered?

Comment: In your diagram, which is the div, and which is the background image?

Comment: @EMiller: I would assume the blue one is the background image since it is supposed to be full width. But I have to admit, I'm rather confused by the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background images do not display outside of their containing elements. That doesn't mean that all or part of a background image cannot be positioned outside its element, just that the parts that are outside the element boundary won't be displayed when the page is rendered.

So in short, yes. You'll have to use a wrapper div.

Comment: Thanks - I did end up using a wrapper so I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to use a wrapper:

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper { width: 100%; background: url(yourimage.png) left center repeat-x; }
#content { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="content">
      My content
   </div>
</div>
```